# Using NSDate properties will be crashed by 'DBAccess' iOS ORM

Tags: ios, orm, dbaccess

I am using DBAccess framework v1.6.12 with Xcode 7.2.1.

Using NSDate properties with a subclass of DBObject will be crashed.

```
<Error>: -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17027eb40
<Warning>: WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17027eb40
<Warning>: void MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 19] Exception Name: NSInvalidArgumentException
<Warning>: void MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *__strong) [Line 20] Exception Reason: -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17027eb40
```

Reproduce:
Set device to Japanese language and setting time format to `NOT to use 24 hours`, then converted date format becomes to a wrong format.

I think whether that DBAccess make convert NSDate to TEXT using NSDateFormatter without setLocale or using currentLocale.

```
// Implements DBDelegate
- (DBAccessSettings*)getCustomSettings {
    DBAccessSettings *settings = [[DBAccessSettings alloc] init];
    settings.useHighPerformanceDates = NO;
    return settings;
}

static void testcode()
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSLog(@"without setLocale=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);

    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    NSLog(@"systemLocale=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);

    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    NSLog(@"en_US_POSIX=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);

    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSLog(@"currentLocale=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);
}

//--- English language or `Use 24 hours` to be ON.
without setLocale=2016/04/04 15:40:00
     systemLocale=2016/04/04 15:40:00
      en_US_POSIX=2016/04/04 15:40:00
    currentLocale=2016/04/04 15:40:00

//--- Japanese language and `Use 24 hours` to be OFF.
without setLocale=2016/04/04 15午後3:40:47
     systemLocale=2016/04/04 15:40:47
      en_US_POSIX=2016/04/04 15:40:47
    currentLocale=2016/04/04 15午後3:40:47
```

So, the stored `NSDate` data converted as String.
Then its column will treat as a TEXT type.

I want DBAccess will use systemLocale or LocaleIdentifier with "en_US_POSIX" when convert between NSDate and TEXT.

Could you tell me how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi RAPT, all dates are stored as 64bit Unsigned Integers, using the EPOCH standard.  A call is made to *NSDate* to get *timeIntervalSince1970*, so provided there is any kind of valid NSDate provided, it should work fine.  But I will try to replicate your issue.  It looks like you are setting the NSDate property with an NSString value, and not a date.  So to be entirely clear, the NSDate property gets a call to *timeIntervalSinceDate*, to get a number and then the other way round, it creates a new NSDate with intervalFrom1970 passing the number back in.  All dates are UTC.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that an important info.   
I added that I'm using DBDelegate to override `useHighPerformanceDates` to be `NO`.

Comment: Hi RAPT,  can you email us at devs@db-access.org.  As this is going to take some back and forth to work out what/why/when...

Comment: Okay. I sent an email.